# resizing vbox disk of encrypted guest disk is not so easy

Tags: linux, virtualbox, encryption, disk

i wanna increase the size of the guest disk in virtualbox, but it is not so simple for
encrypted systems  :-/

I run debian into a vbox with debian disk encryption, no vbox disk encryption.
The guests disk has 7GB, I resized it by doing:

1. open vbox > File > Virtual Media Manager > slide the bar to 30GB size;
2. from cmd line of host:
   vboxmanage modifymedium disk "vmName.vdi" --resize 30000
   (this gave me a non-understandable error msg... whatever..)
3. I started the VM, opened gparted and saw the whole 30GB there... cool
   Off course it was showing the additional ~23GB as unused space.
   I use the gparted slider to resize the partition /dev/sda3 (where my home is)
   to use the whole space, thus going to ~30GB;
4. i rebooted the guest system, logded in reopened gparted at the guest and saw
   /dev/sda3 having 30GB, great!
5. I typed 'du -h' in the guest and saw only the former 7GB there ...  :-/
6. if i 'du -h vmName.dvi' from the host shell i keep seeing only the 7GB there,
   but it does not need to mean much, since the initial setting was already for
   dynamically allocated disk space;
7. From the guest shell i do 'fdisk -l' and see the whole 30GB inside /dev/sda3
   (mounted as /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt ... 30GB);
8. Now i open virtualbox from the guest, open settings for my VM and go to storage.
   There it says:
   Virtual size: 30GB; Actual size: 7GB (?? no idea, maybe it refers to dynamic allocation);

Note: when i encrypt a guest disk, dynamic allocation from virtualbox does not have any effect,
meaning, the encrypted partition goes directly to its full potential size, at leas if i 'du'
its image file from the guest OS. Thus step 6 above should indeed show right alway 30GB;

Well, can anyone help me further audit or solve this problem ??

Thanks a lot!

Host: ubuntu
Guest: debian/openbox on virtualbox, dynamic allocation of HD space

Comment: I just opened the partition again with gparted and could read:
''22.29 GiB of unallocated space within the partition.
To grow the file system to fill the partition, select the partition and choose the menu item:
Partition --> Check."  However option 'check' is disabled in menu.... still need help!!